# watchPosition() fires callback only once

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, geolocation, gps

I am writing a watchPosition function for a geofencing feature in MapDotNet's Touchgeo (http://www.mapdotnet.com/index.php/component/content/article?id=131). On initial load, everything works excellently; on refresh, I only get one line of debug messages, indicating only one callback, and the GPS on my phone never turns on. Here is my watchPosition function:

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
    function success(pos) {
        $('#debug')
            .prepend(
                $('<div></div>').text('accuracy: ' + pos.coords.accuracy)
            )
            .css({
                textAlign: 'right',
                color: 'black'
            });
        var endpoint = isc.touchgeo.dataServicesEndpoint + "Map/mapname/Features/geofence?x={x}&y={y}&role={role}"
            .replace("{x}", pos.coords.longitude)
            .replace("{y}", pos.coords.latitude)
            .replace("{role}", isc.touchgeo.authenticationMgr.getAuthorizationRecord().Role);
        $.getJSON(endpoint, function success(data) {
            $('#debug')
                .prepend(
                    $('<div></div>').text('features: ' + data.length)
                )
                .css({
                    textAlign: 'right',
                    color: 'black'
                });
            for (layer in data) {
                if (layer in geofencingRules) {
                    geofencingRules[layer](data[layer]);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    function error(error) {
        $('#debug')
            .prepend(
                $('<div></div>').text('error: ' + error.code)
            )
            .css({
                textAlign: 'right',
                color: 'black'
            });
    },
    {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        maximumAge: 15000,
    }
);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically, the `maximumAge` on positionOptions was telling `watchPosition()` to use data from before the page was refreshed. Consequently, the GPS was never turned on and `watchPosition()` didn't receive data. The way to fix this is to have

```
var maximumAge = 0;
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
    function success(pos) {
        maximumAge = 15000;
        $('#debug')
            .prepend(
                $('<div></div>').text('accuracy: ' + pos.coords.accuracy)
            )
            .css({
                textAlign: 'right',
                color: 'black'
            });
        var endpoint = isc.touchgeo.dataServicesEndpoint + "Map/mapname/Features/geofence?x={x}&y={y}&role={role}"
            .replace("{x}", pos.coords.longitude)
            .replace("{y}", pos.coords.latitude)
            .replace("{role}", isc.touchgeo.authenticationMgr.getAuthorizationRecord().Role);
        $.getJSON(endpoint, function success(data) {
            $('#debug')
                .prepend(
                    $('<div></div>').text('features: ' + data.length)
                )
                .css({
                    textAlign: 'right',
                    color: 'black'
                });
            for (layer in data) {
                if (layer in geofencingRules) {
                    geofencingRules[layer](data[layer]);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    function error(error) {
        $('#debug')
            .prepend(
                $('<div></div>').text('error: ' + error.code)
            )
            .css({
                textAlign: 'right',
                color: 'black'
            });
    },
    {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        maximumAge: maximumAge,
    }
);
```

That is, pass to maximumAge a variable that is initialized to 0 but incremented to 15000 on the first callback.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Does setting the value of maximumAge in your callback actually do anything other than change your local variable? Isn't the setting passed as value rather than as reference?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but at the bottom I use the variable as the third, options argument to the watchPosition function. That 4 year time travel, though.